# Mutexes. What even?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, thread-safety, mutex, atomic

I am learning about computer architecture and how operating systems work. I have a few questions about how mutexes work.

**Question 1**

```
add_to_list(&list, &elem):
    mutex m;
    lock_mutex(m);
    ...

remove_from_list(&list):
    mutex m;
    lock_mutex(m);
    ...
```

These two functions instantiate their own mutex, which means they point to different places in memory and so one does not lock the other and effectively doesn't accomplish what we want--`list` to be protected.

How do we get two different functions to use the same mutex? Do we define a global variable? If so, how do you share this global variable throughout an entire program that is potentially spread throughout multiple files?

**Question 2**

```
mutex m;

modify_A():
    lock_mutex(m);
    A += 1;

modify_B():
    lock_mutex(m);
    B += 1;
```

These two functions modify different spaces in memory. Does that mean I need a unique mutex for each function / or piece of data? If I were to have a global `mutex` variable that I used for both functions, a thread calling `modify_A()` would block another thread trying to call `modify_B()`

Which brings me to my last question...

**Question 3**

A mutex seems like it just blocks a thread from running a piece of code until whatever thread is currently running that same code finishes. This is to create atomicity and protect the integrity of the data being used by a thread. However, the same piece of memory can be modified from many different places in a program. Which makes me think we have to use one mutex throughout an entire program, which would result in a lot of needless blocking of other threads.

Considering that pretty much every function in a given program is going to be modifying data, if we use a single mutex throughout a program, that means each function call will be blocked while that mutex is in use by another thread, even if the data it needs to access is unrelated.

Doesn't that effectively eliminate the gains from having multiple threads? If only one thread can run at a given time?

I feel like I'm totally misunderstanding how mutexes work, so please ELI5!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, you make it a global variable, or otherwise accessible to the required functions through some kind of convenience method or whatever. Global variables can be shared between translation units too, but that's language/system dependent. In C you'd just put an `extern mutex m` in a header that everyone shares and then define that mutex as `mutex m` in exactly one of your translation units.
2. If you don't want changes to `B` to block other threads from modifying `A`, yes, you'd use two different mutexes. If you want to lock both at the same time, you would share the mutex.
3. Multiple threads can run at the same time as long as no two of them are inside the critical section protected by a certain mutex at the same time. That's the whole point - everything goes on nice and parallel, but you use the mutex to serialize access to a specific resource or critical section you need protected.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying 1 & 2. As a follow-up to your answer on 3: Wouldn't there need to be mutexes in every function that modifies either an argument passed in or a global?

Comment: That depends on if you care about protecting them against simultaneous updates or not. Yes, if that state needs to be protected, you need to have a mutex for that.

Comment: Trying to think of a situation where I wouldn't want to protect against that...

Comment: ‍♂️, well if you need 'em you need 'em and if you don't, you don't.

Answer (score 0):

You typically use a mutex to protect some particular piece of shared data. If the vast majority of your code's time is spent accessing one single piece of shared data, then you won't get much of a performance improvement from threads precisely because only one thread can safely access that piece of shared data at a time.

If you happen to fall into this situation, there are more complex techniques than mutexes. Fortunately, it's fairly rare (unless you're implementing operating systems or low-level libraries) so you can get away with using mutexes for a very large fraction of your synchronization needs.